# Where is the node for crx explorer stored in cq5 respository

Tags: aem

I am looking to find the node (source code ) for http://mycq5.com:4502/crx/explorer/browser/index.jsp in CQ5. I searched crxde I couldn't find where this is located. Can anyone let me know how these urls are mapped inside repository. I need to understand the url and mapping structure and find source code to some of the functionality.
URLS that I am interested are
http://myccq.com:4502/crx/de/index.jsp
http://myccq.com:4502/crx/explorer/ui/aceditor.jsp

Answer (score 3):

*CRXDE Lite* and *CRX Explorer* are part of the CRX repository. As such, they are not based on Sling and there are no JCR nodes related to them. They are shipped as OSGi bundles listed in the Felix console:

- com.adobe.granite.crxde-lite
- com.adobe.granite.crx-explorer

Files you are looking for are embedded as resources in these bundles.